# How can I make tag page title dynamic

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, wordpress-hook

I have problem with my PHP code and I really need your help!
I want to make my tag page title dynamically and do these two steps:

1 : Get the number of posts inside this tag

2 : show the number (posts is this tag) before tag page title

I already get the number of posts but I cannot hook it into page title

this is the way how I get the number of posts :

```
add_filter( ‘the_title’, ‘mbpt_strip_tags_for_title’ );
function mbpt_strip_tags_for_title($title) {

    if ( is_tag() ) {
        $tag_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        $term = get_tag( $tag_id );
        $tags_post_count = $term->count;
        $title = $tags_post_count . $title;
    } else {
        $title = $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Not really clear on what is going on here... also , what are you receiving? if you are receiving just the title without the $tags_post_count - it means that your if statement is wrong ... try loosing the if(is_tag()) and its else and see if you receive : 27Sometitle...  also ... you need to share some more data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`the_title` is the post title, the title of the Tag Archive would be `the_archive_title`

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'mbpt_strip_tags_for_title' );
function mbpt_strip_tags_for_title($title) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
        if ( is_a( $term, 'WP_Term' ) && $term->taxonomy === 'post_tag' ) {
        return $term->count . ' ' . $term->name;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: I add this to my function.php but it doesnt work! Do you sure that this code is for tag title page?

Comment: Yes. Updated to specifically do post tag.  Unless you're using a custom taxonomy.  Tested on a clean WP Installation.  If it's not working for you, then your theme archive.php template has an override and doesn't use `the_archive_title`

Comment: how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Look in your theme for archive.php or tag.php https://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates

Comment: My theme just have one archive.php that when i removed it nothind happed and the page still usable. My archive template build with elementor how can i find that directory or hook?

Comment: There are potentially other override page templates. Check the link I posted.